# How to pass parameter to TypeConverter derived class

Tags: c#, .net, typeconverter

I would like to pass some parameter to class derived from TypeConverter. Tell me please, how can I do it? 
For example, I have this class:

```
public class DDlExample
{
        [TypeConverter(typeof(ExClassConverter))]
        public int Bounds { get; set; }
}

class ExClassConverter : TypeConverter
{
  public int FirstParam{get;set;}
...
}
```

I would like to pass value FirstParam like this:

```
public class DDlExample
{
        [TypeConverter(typeof(ExClassConverter), ***FirstParam=2***)]
        public int Bounds { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible?

It seems this task has no solution. I'll try to restate the problem.
I have one class derived from TypeConverter and I apply it to different properties to show different values drop down list. How can I define which properties from `ExClassConverter : TypeConverter` to fill drop down list with appropriate values?

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property,AllowMultiple=true,Inherited=true)]   
public class ParamDesc:Attribute
{
    public ParamDesc(int PD) { DictID = PD; }
    public int DictID { get; set; }
}

public class DDlExample
{
    [ParamDesc(1)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExClassConverter))]
    public int Bounds { get; set; }

    [ParamDes(2)]
    [TypeConverter(typeof(ExClassConverter))]
    public int Rounds { get; set; }
}

class ExClassConverter : TypeConverter
{

private List<string> LSValues1 = new List<string>(new string[] {"first","second","third"});
private List<string> LSValues2 = new List<string>(new string[] {"apple","melon","grapes"});

public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
{
   if (sourceType == typeof(string))
      return true;
    return base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);

}

public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
{            
   if (sourceType == typeof(int))
           return (sourceType == typeof(int)?true:false);
    return base.CanConvertTo(context, sourceType);
}

public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
    CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destType)
{
        if (value is int)
        {          
            return LSValues1[(int)value];
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destType);
}
public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context,
CultureInfo culture, object value)
{
    if (value is string)
    {
        return LSValues1.IndexOf(value.ToString());
    }
    return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);

}

public override bool GetStandardValuesSupported(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    return true;
}

public override bool GetStandardValuesExclusive(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    return true;
}

public override TypeConverter.StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    StandardValuesCollection svc = new StandardValuesCollection(LSValues1);
    return svc;
}
}
```

Comment: Nope, not possible. Best 'solution' is to created derived classes from `ExClassConverter` with those defaults set in the constructor.

Answer (score 9):

I have solved the task. I used `ITypeDescriptorContext context` at methods ConvertTo and ConvertFrom:

```
if (context != null)
{
    AttributeCollection ua = context.PropertyDescriptor.Attributes;                    
    ParamDesc cca = (ParamDesc)ua[typeof(ParamDesc)];    
    if (cca != null)
        System.Console.WriteLine("Attribute value is " + cca.DictID.ToString());
}
```

Comment: For those reading this answer, I can tell that there was omitted information. Obviously "ParamDesc" is an attribute, and it must be one that the OP implemented with the DictID member to indicate which set of standard values he wanted for that property. The properties (that also have the TypeConverter attribute) were then decorated with this attribute to pass the info along to the type converter in the manner shown in this post. The GetStandardValues checks this property as shown and decides what to return based on that.

Answer (score 4):

Old question, but ...

For sake of completeness, a solution for what appears to be OP's problem is: just check the property name the type converter is being called against.  For example,

```
public override StandardValuesCollection GetStandardValues(ITypeDescriptorContext context)
{
    StandardValuesCollection svc;
    if (context.PropertyDescriptor.Name == "Bounds")
        svc = new StandardValuesCollection(LSValues1);
    else if (context.PropertyDescriptor.Name == "Rounds")
        svc = new StandardValuesCollection(LSValues2);
    return svc;
}
```

This solution avoids need for OP's extra attribute applied to the property.